# How to obtain document vectors in doc2vec in gensim

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I know to obtain a document vector for a given tag in doc2vec using `print(model.docvecs['recipe__11'])`.

My document vectors are either recipes (tags start with `recipe__`), newspapers (tags start with `news__`) or ingredients (tags start with `ingre__`)

Now I want to retrieve all the document vectors of recipes. The pattern of my recipe documents is `recipe__<some number>` (e.g., recipe__23, recipe__34). I am interested in knowing if it possible to obtain multiple document vectors using a pattern (e.g., tags starting with `recipe__`)

Please help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no pattern-retrieval, but you can access the list of all known (string) doc-tags in `model.docvecs.offset2doctag`. You could then loop over that list to find all matches, and retrieve each individually.

Also, all the doc-vectors are in a large array `model.docvecs.doctag_syn0` And, if you've used exclusively string doc-tags, then the position of a tag in `offset2doctag` will be exactly the index of the corresponding vector in `doctag_syn0`. That would allow you to use numpy 'mask indexing' to grab a subset of vectors as a new array, like:

```
recipes_mask = [tag.startswith('recipe_') for tag in model.dacvecs.offset2doctag]
recipes_vectors = model.docvecs.doctag_syn0[recipes_mask]
```

Of course, this array-of-vectors no longer has the recipes in the same positions as the original, so you'd need extra steps to know where (for example) the 'recipe__11' vector is in `recipes_vectors`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. :) After obtaining the recipe document vectors can't I use commands like `most.similar` (as they are not in original positions now)?

Comment: Correct. The example above just gives you the raw vectors, not a full `Doc2Vec` or `Word2Vec` or `KeyedVectors` object (that would have the utility method `most_similar()`). You could perhaps mimic that method though, or force the subset into a consructed `KeyedVectors`. But you may instead want to do `most_similar()` across all doc-vecs, obtaining a larger number of top-results, *then* filter for one type of vector.

Comment: That is a great idea. I will perform `most similar` to all doc-vecs and filter that results. Thanks a lot :)